Employer Demanding Charge Back
I reside in Arkansas, the job I got fired from is trying to demand I repay where they got scammed. I did deal with the calls from the scammers. The job never got written consent from me, and they threatened to fire me to get me to agree verbally to pay them back. Do I have to pay them back? Are they allowed to take any of my last check?

We can't give you legal advice. You need to consult a lawyer locally.

For legal reasons, Law Stackexchange is not allowed to give legal advice on specific cases. Your situation sounds as if you should talk to a lawyer where you live, and possibly also to the police (the lawyer will advise). The details of your situation should not be posted on the web.

No. They have to pay your salary or you take them to court. They can take you to court for their loss. But they would have to prove that you caused any damages, which they likely can’t, and that you are at fault so much that it isn’t covered by the normal risk that sn employer has to carry. Like handing over money against company orders. So they have very little chance.

The details depend on the details. We don't know what the OP agreed to, and what the OP did.
